# Matplotlib - Fill_Between doesn't seem work

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm new to python and learned a ton over the past 2 weeks. I have just started learning and experimenting with matplotlib.pylot. In my code, I have 3 seperate simple graphs on the same plot, in the third graph there are 2 lines. I am trying to have a green fill_between when y2 > y3, and red fill_between when y3 > y2. I have taken a look at other code, and they look identical to mine, but for some reason it doesn't work. 
Any help?

There are a few commented lines, they are just experimentation.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
from matplotlib import style


style.use('fivethirtyeight')

def create_points(nPoints):
    xs = []
    ys = []
    for i in range(nPoints):
        rand = random.randrange(0,3*nPoints)
        xs.append(i)
        ys.append(rand)
    return xs, ys

x,y = create_points(200)
x1,y1 = create_points(200)
x2, y2 = create_points(200)
x3, y3 = create_points(200)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((6,1), (0,0), rowspan = 1, colspan = 1)
plt.title('Subplot2grid Method')
plt.ylabel('Plot 1')

ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((6,1), (1,0), rowspan = 4, colspan = 1, sharex = ax1)
plt.ylabel('Plot 2')
ax2_xtwin = ax2.twinx()

ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((6,1), (5,0), rowspan = 1, colspan = 1, sharex = ax1)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('Plot 3')


ax2_xtwin.fill_between(x,0,y, facecolor = '#0079a3', alpha = 0.4)
#ax2v.axes.yaxis.set_ticklables([])
ax2_xtwin.grid(False)
ax2_xtwin.set_ylim(0, 1.5*max(y))


ax3.plot(x2, y2, x2, y3, linewidth = 1, label = 'x2y2 plot', color = 'k')

#ax3.plot(x3, y3, linewidth = 1, label = 'x3y3 plot', color = 'firebrick')

ax3.fill_between(x2, y2, y3, where = (y2 >= y3), facecolor = 'darkgreen',
                 edgecolor = 'g', alpha = 0.5, interpolate = True)
ax3.fill_between(x2, y2, y3, where = (y2 <= y3), facecolor = 'firebrick',
                 edgecolor = 'r', alpha = 0.5, interpolate = True)

#Print Points

ax1.plot(x, y, linewidth = 1, label = 'xy plot', color = 'gold')

ax2.plot(x1, y1, linewidth = 1, label = 'x1y1 plot', color = 'sandybrown')

#ax3.plot(x2, y2, linewidth = 1, label = 'x2y2 plot', color = 'darkgreen')

#ax3.plot(x3, y3, linewidth = 1, label = 'x3y3 plot', color = 'firebrick')

plt.subplots_adjust(left = 0.15, bottom = 0.1, right = 0.9, top = 0.9,
                    wspace = 0.2, hspace = 0)

plt.show()
```

Comment: If you want someone to find out why a certain code does not work as expected you would need to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
Sorry I miss-understood your question.

If you delete color='k' in ax3.plot and mask the y2 after the first fill_between it works fine.
Change to...

```
ax3.plot(x2, y2, x2, y3, linewidth = 1, label = 'x2y2 plot')

ax3.fill_between(x2, y2, y3, where = (y2 >= y3), color = "g",
                 edgecolor = 'g', alpha = 0.5, interpolate = True)
y2 = np.ma.masked_greater(y2, y3)
ax3.fill_between(x2, y2, y3, where = (y2 <= y3), color="r",
                 edgecolor = 'r', alpha = 0.5, interpolate = True)
```

I'm not sure why but the facecolor didn't work on my side, so I changed to color.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I included the x axis and y axis code. The array size shouldn't be an issue since I am made them all equal in size.